# Python3 socket "AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, module

I'm new with coding but i'm trying to send a file via sockets. In this case a jpg but the idea is to make it send whatever files in whatever size. I can't find enough information on this and i have been trying to google and checking on stackoverflow but wont find anything that will help me so i decided to ask here on stackoverflow. I'm using PYTHON3

### the idea is a server and a client. The client will send a file to the server. Here is the code....Thankful for help.

```
#SERVER CODE

import socket
import os
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("socket created...")
except:
    print("failed creating a socket.")

def srv_1(host, port):
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print("...Server Listening on port:", port, host)

    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("ACCEPTED CONNECTION:-> ", addr)
        recivedData = c.recv(1024).decode() #this is going to be the 
bits of file
        print("file size is :", recivedData)
        inpa = input("ACCEPT THE FILE? Y/N : ")
        if inpa == 'Y':
            acceptingFile = c.recv(1024).decode()
            while recivedData > 1024:
                data = c.recv(1024).decode()
                print("Reciving entire file:", recivedData)
                f = open(data,+"jpg", "wb")
                print("...Done saving...")
        elif inpa == 'N':
            s.close()
            print("...SOCKET CLOSED...")
    f = open(data,+"jpg", "wb")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    srv_1('127.0.0.1', 5460)
```

---

### #CLIENT CODE

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5460

def myC_F():

    try:
        s.connect((host, port))
        print("connected to socket")
    except:
        print("failed connecting to: ", host, port)

    fPath = input("Enter file to send:> ")
    fSize = os.path.getsize(fPath)
    fSize = str(fSize)
    s.send(fSize.encode())
    print("...DONE SENDING SIZE :", fSize)
    while True:
        with open(fPath, "rb") as f:
            s.sendall(f.encode())


myC_F()
```

---

### The error i am getting is

```
$python3 my_vers_CLIENT.py
connected to socket
Enter file to send:> /home/pythonious/Desktop/171.jpg
...DONE SENDING SIZE : 41846
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_vers_CLIENT.py", line 30, in <module>
    myC_F()
  File "my_vers_CLIENT.py", line 24, in myC_F
    s.sendall(f.encode())
AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use `s.sendall(f.read())` instead of `s.sendall(f.encode())`